# J2me:Displayable.setTicker() automatically switch off nokia mobile

Tags: java, java-me, lcdui, nokia-s40

I am developing a mobile application in j2me. In that application I use 6 screen which is extends from the classes `javax.microedition.lcdui.Form`, `javax.microedition.lcdui.List`, etc. I create a `Displayable(javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable)` object displayable. I made an assignment displayable equals to my screen objects. After that I set a ticker using `displayable.setTicker(Ticker ticker)`.

The above situations are only part of my application. My application runs in "Sony ericsson z530i" mobile successfully but in "nokia c200" mobile which is nokia-s40 series sdk device `displayable.setTicker()` automatically switch off the mobile.

I cannot resolve the solution. So please help me to solve the solution. Give me your valuable ideas.

Comment: did you try to test if same error happens with simplest possible code? like eg `new Form("form").setTicker(new Ticker("ticker"))` - so that your midlet has nothing besides that. If device would fail with such simple code, then it's most likely Nokia's bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.There is heap memory exception is throws sometimes in application. So it will terminate.

Now I reduce the memory leaks in my coding. Now it's working correctly.